# How to combine map and clamp function together

Tags: javascript, function

There are two functions

```
const clamp = (num, a, b) => Math.max(Math.min(num, Math.max(a, b)), Math.min(a, b));
const map = (x, a, b, c, d, clamp) => (x - a) * (d - c) / (b - a) + c

const c = map(-50, 0, 1, 0, 100)
const _c = clamp(c, 0, 1)
console.log(_c, c)
```

Is there any way that the two function could be combined, something like

```
const _c = map(-50, 0, 1, 0, 100, {clamp: true})
```

so that I don't need copy parameters from the map function to get the new value within the parameters range.

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty easy, just create a single function and that sequentially executes the original map function and if the `clamp` parameter is `true` then compute that and return it. Check below for the code.

```
const map(x, a, b, c, d, clamp) {
   const map_result = (x - a) * (d - c) / (b - a) + c;
   if (clamp) {
       const clamp_result = Math.max(Math.min(map_result, Math.max(a, b)), Math.min(a, b));
       return clamp_result
   }

   return map_result;
}
```

You can use it like this:
`const _c = map(-50, 0, 1, 0, 100, true)`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the function to the clamp function and use it inside the same. Or if the functions are in same location you can just invoke it inside the clamp function

```js
const map = (x, a, b, c, d, clamp) => (x - a) * (d - c) / (b - a) + c


 
const _map = (x, a, b, c, d, map) =>  Math.max(Math.min(map(x, a, b, c, d), Math.max(a, b)), Math.min(a, b));


const a =  _map(-50, 0, 1, 0, 100, map)
console.log(a)
```